# Select every nth row from database, cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a very large table and I need to get a year's view of all the data. But If I use:

**select * from table where startTime >= date1 and endTime <= date2**

The size of the data is too large, the browser won't display it and it will cause my server to crash.

So I need to shrink the ammount of data I select from the databse, like only select one point in a day.

But my primary key is very complex and doesn't have a column like 1,2,3 as Id. So I cannot do something simple like:

**select * from table where startTime >= date1 and endTime <= date2 and Id%10=0**

Is there a way to select every nth row in cassandra?

Comment: what is your table schema ?